# SQL Server 2005 FOR XML limitation

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I am using the following script in SQL Server 2005 to create a xml output

```
select 
    mst.Reference "Reference",
    convert(varchar(10), mst.CreatedOn, 121) "Date_Created",
    convert(varchar(10), mst.DueOn, 121) "Date_Due",
    isnull(mst.Amount1, 0.00) "Amt_1",
    isnull(mst.Tax1, 0.00) "Tax_1",
    isnull(mst.Item_Count, 0.00) "No_Of_Items",
    isnull(mst.Amount2, 0.00) "Amt_2",
    isnull(mst.Tax2, 0.00) "Tax_2",
    isnull(mst.Total, 0.00) "Total",
    isnull(mst.Note, '') "Notes",
    (select
        det.Reference "Reference",
        det.Itm_Num "Order",
        isnull(det.Description, '') "Description",
        det.Code "Code",
        isnull(det.Amount1, 0.00) "Amt_1",
        isnull(det.Tax1, 0.00) "Tax_1",
        isnull(det.Amount2, 0.00) "Amt_2",
        isnull(det.Tax2, 0.00) "Tax_2",
        isnull(det.Note, '') "Notes"
     from tblDetail det
     where det.Mst_Reference = mst.Reference
     order by det.Itm_num
     for xml path ('item'), type)
from tblMaster mst
for xml path ('master'), root('root'), type
```

This is however returning me a blank xml without any errors but if I change it to just fetch 4 records from the master it creates and returns the xml. IS there a limit on the no of records on xml creation?

thanks

Comment: How are you applying the four record limit?

Comment: how many records do you have in your table? how do you check that xml is empty?

Comment: I just tried trial and error and found that it was returning 4 records...but i think that value can increase of decrease based on the no of records in the deail table...

Comment: There aren't many records now...its only around 70 records in the master and around 1100 records in the detail table...

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling you're exceeding the size of data SSMS is allowing to be displayed.
Try adjusting the size in SSMS here:

**Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Srver -> Results to Grid -> XML data**

Change 2MB to something larger

Comment: What version of SSMS are you running? I only see 1MB, 2MB, 5MB OR "unlimited" as the only options.

Comment: What does running DATALENGTH() on your query return?
ex:
SELECT
  DATALENGTH
  (
    (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        <your query>
      FOR XML AUTO, TYPE      
    )
  );

Comment: I get 308852 for the datalength

Comment: Puzzled by you still seeing a blank result set in SSMS. However, the 308852 you're getting back is proof that you are, in fact, getting data back.